# Use rsync with gitlab-ci.yml to sync Wordpress theme folders

Tags: git, shell, rsync, sshpass

While trying to use `.gitlab-ci.yml` to automatically deploy my theme to my production server, I receive a error:

**The command executed:** using a *ubuntu:16.04* image

```
$ apt update -y && apt install openssh-client sshpass rsync -y
$ rsync -avh --progress --delete --rsh="sshpass -p $STAGE_FTP_PASS ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no " --exclude=.git ./ $STAGE_FTP_USER@my.wp.address/project-folder/wp-content/themes/sg-coesfeld-theme/
```

**The error result:**

```
sshpass: invalid option -- 'o'
protocol version mismatch -- is your shell clean?
(see the rsync man page for an explanation)
rsync error: protocol incompatibility (code 2) at compat.c(176) [sender=3.1.1]
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

I am using the exact same `.gitlab-ci.yml`, server, FTP account, runner and gitlab hosting successfully to auto-deploy in other git repos.

The only thing that has changed is the source git repository and the `/project-folder/`.

To be honest I do not know where to start and how to track down this issue, so I am happy about any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$STAGE_FTP_PASS` must be empty so the command would become

```
sshpass -p ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
```

so `sshpass` would think `-p ssh` is the password and `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` is the command.

Comment: thanks @pynexj, this is correct. I cannot `echo $STAGE_FTP_PASS` even if its set, but thats another problem and gitlab specific I think… thanks a lot! :) excellent help.

Comment: I have added a more detailed solution regarding my exact problem, if there are others having the same issue.

Comment: Took me long enough to find this... in fact I was executing from an unprotected branch but had gitlab protect the password variable, which resulted in an empty variable hence the same (partial) error `sshpass: invalid option -- 'o'`

Answer (score 1):

As @pynexj already has said, `$STAGE_FTP_PASS` was an empty string, which caused the error. I have tried this using `echo $STAGE_FTP_USER` inside my script.

While inserting the secret variables, I have checked the box **[X] Protected**, which has an explanation attached: *This variable will be passed only to pipelines running on protected branches and tags.*

Searching for *protected branches* I have noticed, that in *Settings > Repository > Protected Branches* no protected branch was set.

So I could choose between unchecking the `[ ] Protected` checkbox, so that every branch can use the secret variables, or go with the more secure approach and add my branch (for example `master`) as a protected branch.

Now everything works great again. Thanks again to @pynexj for pointing out what causes the problem in the script.